# Streamline dplyr mutation of selected groups

Tags: r, dplyr

**A general question:**

Is there a way to use dplyr to identify groups of interest and mutate only those groups?

**An Instantiation of Said Question**

Imagine I have some values, which are labeled as being part of groups.

In some groups, the spread of the values is too great.

I want to make an adjustment to the lower values of those groups.

I can generate some synthetic data like so:

```
groups <- floor(runif(1000,1,100))
values <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
df     <- data.frame(group=groups,val=values)
```

I can identify groups of interest like so:

```
groups_to_adjust <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(diff=max(val)-min(val)) %>% filter(diff>4) %>% select(group)
```

I can then adjust those groups like so:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(val=ifelse(group %in% groups_to_adjust$group, ifelse(val<0,val+4,val), val))
```

Ideally, all of this could be done in a single dplyr chain. Is there a clean way to achieve that? I imagine:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% group_filter(max(val)-min(val)>4) %>% mutate(val=ifelse(val<0,val+4,val)) %>% ungroupfilter()
```

Or something similar.

Comment: `ifelse`, `case_when`, or `filter %>% mutate %>% left_join` seem like the options.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test the code, but I think this does what you want:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
       mutate(val = ifelse(max(val) - min(val) > 4 & val < 0, val + 4, val))
```

One test case with a small data frame:

```
df
   group   val
1      1  0.00
2      1 -1.56
3      1  0.70
4      1  0.30
5      2 -1.66
6      2 -0.49
7      2 -0.36
8      2  1.67
9      3  0.94
10     3  1.62
11     3  0.89
12     3 -0.53

df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
       mutate(val = ifelse(max(val) - min(val) > 3 & val < 0, val + 4, val))

Source: local data frame [12 x 2]
Groups: group [3]

   group   val
   (int) (dbl)
1      1  0.00
2      1 -1.56
3      1  0.70
4      1  0.30
5      2  2.34
6      2  3.51
7      2  3.64
8      2  1.67
9      3  0.94
10     3  1.62
11     3  0.89
12     3 -0.53
```

Only the negative values in the second group get replaced because the other two groups difference is smaller than `3`.

Comment: I suspect it does, though it seems like this particular form will result in a fair amount of recalculation and does not syntactically separate the group filtering from the mutation. Perhaps there is no good way.

Comment: I think you are correct in that sense. With a group filter, it avoids a lot of unnecessary calculations for unintended groups.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(val = ifelse(max(val) - min(val) > 3 , ifelse(val < 0, val + 4, val), val)`. I think you can maybe give this a try which kind of separates the comparison of group and val.